# Find the set of convergence and the sum of the following power series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^3x^n $

Tags: power-series

This is the exercise: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^3x^n.$$

I only managed to find the the set of convergence to be $(-1,1)$.
The answer should be: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^3x^n =\frac{x(x^2+4x+1)}{(1-x)^4}.$$

Comment: @Math_QED mispelling

Comment: Please define what you mean by "set of convergence"?

Comment: **Hint:** think about the formula for geometric series and use derivatives carefully.

Comment: @amWhy I calculated the radius of convergence, which is 1, then I tested the convergence for x=1 and x=-1 and by using Leibniz test, I found out that the two series are divergent

Comment: @amWhy: I believe it means the set of values that $x$ can take and the series still converge (I’d suggest using the ratio test, personally, to prove this is the “set of convergence”).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From sum of geometric series we know that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ when $x\in(-1,1)$. From a known theorem about power series we can take the derivative on both sides and get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$. Multiply both sides by $x$ to get $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$. Now you can take a derivative on both sides again, and continue this way. It is a bit of work but it will get you to the result you need.

Comment: Downvoter, can you explain what exactly you didn't like in my answer?

Comment: My total rep decreases every morning without Any reason. No one told me Why ?. So (+1) for you.

Comment: It is not about the points. I just wonder what might be the problem in my answer. When I downvote a post I usually explain what I didn't like there.

Comment: The downvoter is not me.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's not you. I guess the downvoter decided to ignore my question. Well, ok then.

Comment: @Mark: probably someone disagreed with you answering what might be considered by some to be a Problem Statement Wuestion. Either way, just answer whatever questions you feel like answering, and know that you got a $+1$ from me :)

Comment: @Clayton, yes, probably. Just thought maybe I wrote something wrong in the answer, but I see that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Given that
$$(1-x)^{-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}x^n,$$
You differentiate the equation once to get 
$$-(1-x)^{-2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}nx^{n-1},$$
And multiplying both sides by $x$ you get 
$$-x(1-x)^{-2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}nx^{n}$$
Now you differentiate again, and then again...

Answer (score 0):

some ingredients:
$$ (1-x)^{-2} = \left( \begin{array}{c}1\\1 \end{array}\right) + \left( \begin{array}{c}2\\1 \end{array}\right) x +\left( \begin{array}{c}3\\1 \end{array}\right) x^2 +\left( \begin{array}{c}4\\1 \end{array}\right) x^3 +\left( \begin{array}{c}5\\1 \end{array}\right) x^4  +\left( \begin{array}{c}6\\1 \end{array}\right) x^5 + \cdots   $$

$$ (1-x)^{-3} = \left( \begin{array}{c}2\\2 \end{array}\right) + \left( \begin{array}{c}3\\2 \end{array}\right) x +\left( \begin{array}{c}4\\2 \end{array}\right) x^2 +\left( \begin{array}{c}5\\2 \end{array}\right) x^3 +\left( \begin{array}{c}6\\2 \end{array}\right) x^4  +\left( \begin{array}{c}7\\2 \end{array}\right) x^5 + \cdots   $$

$$ (1-x)^{-4} = \left( \begin{array}{c}3\\3 \end{array}\right) + \left( \begin{array}{c}4\\3 \end{array}\right) x +\left( \begin{array}{c}5\\3 \end{array}\right) x^2 +\left( \begin{array}{c}6\\3 \end{array}\right) x^3 +\left( \begin{array}{c}7\\3 \end{array}\right) x^4  +\left( \begin{array}{c}8\\3 \end{array}\right) x^5 + \cdots   $$

Answer (score 0):

Similar basis, but a different strategy: as $\;\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n=\dfrac1{1-x}$ the successive derivatives yield:

\begin{alignat}{2}
&\bullet\enspace\Bigl(\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\Bigr)'=\sum_{n\ge 1}n\, x^{n-1}=\frac1{(1-x)^2},&\text{so}\quad& \sum_{n\ge 1}n\, x^{n}=\frac x{(1-x)^2},\\
&\bullet\enspace\Bigl(\sum_{n\ge 1}x^n\Bigr)''=\sum_{n\ge 1}n(n-1)\, x^{n-2}=\frac2{(1-x)^3},&\quad\text{so}\quad&\sum_{n\ge 1}n(n-1)\, x^{n}=\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3}, \\
&\bullet\enspace\Bigl(\sum_{n\ge 1}x^n\Bigr)'''=\sum_{n\ge 1}n(n-1)(n-2)\, x^{n-2}=\frac6{(1-x)^4},&\quad\text{so}\quad&\sum_{n\ge 1}n(n-1)(n-2)\, x^{n}=\frac{6x^3}{(1-x)^4}.
\end{alignat}
Now $n^3=n(n-1)(n-2)+3n^2-2n$,  $\quad n^2=n(n-1)+n$, therefore
$$n^3=n(n-1)(n-2)+3n(n-1)+n, $$
so that by linearity,
$$\sum_{n\ge 1}n^3x^n=\frac{6x^3}{(1-x)^4}+\frac{6x^2}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.$$